# dart mixin that extends a super type, causes client classes to have to implement the supertype's methods

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use a mixin in dart, but I get a compile-time error saying that the class that uses the mixin needs to implement a method on the superType of the mixin. This seems ridiculous as the reason for a mixin is to give the class the method so that it doesn't have to implement it. My code:

```
abstract class IFormView<EntityType, SubmitResponseType>
    implements IOnInitialise {
  FormGroup form;
  BuildContext context;
  EntityType entity;

  void hydrateFormFromEntity();
  void hydrateEntityFromForm();

  Future<void> submit();
  Future<void> submitViaField();
  Future<SubmitResponseType> submitMethod();

  void onSubmitSuccess(SubmitResponseType result);
  void onSubmitError(VpAppError error);

  /// This is to show or not show form error messages upon first opening
  void setupForm();
}


abstract class AFormView<EntityType, SubmitResponseType>
    implements IFormView<EntityType, SubmitResponseType> {
  FormGroup form;

  void setupForm() {
    form.markAsDirty();
    form.markAsUntouched();
  }
}

abstract class ARemoteFormView<EntityType extends IEntity<EntityType>,
        SubmitResponseType> extends AFormView<EntityType, SubmitResponseType>
    implements IOnInitialise {
  @override
  Future<void> submitViaField() async {
    return context
        .read(loadingIndicatorStateNotifierProvider)
        .pressed(() => submit());
  }

  @override
  @mustCallSuper
  @protected
  void onInitialise() {
    assert(form != null);
    hydrateFormFromEntity();
    setupForm();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> submit() async {
    await HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
    hydrateEntityFromForm();
    try {
      final SubmitResponseType result = await submitMethod();
      onSubmitSuccess(result);
    } catch (error) {
      onSubmitError(VpAppError<dynamic>(
          message: error.message as String, originalError: error));
    }
  }

  @protected
  void onSubmitError(VpAppError<dynamic> error) {
    vpSnackBarError(
        title: 'There has been an error',
        body: error.message ?? '',
        context: context);
  }
}

class SignInFormViewModel
    with ARemoteFormView<UserCredentialEntity, UserCredential> {
  SignInFormViewModel() {
    onInitialise();
  }

  @override
  BuildContext context;
  @override
  UserCredentialEntity entity;

  @override
  FormGroup form = FormGroup({
    UserCredentialFieldNames.emailAddress: FormControl<String>(
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    UserCredentialFieldNames.password:
        FormControl<String>(validators: [Validators.required])
  });

  void showForgotPasswordDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog<bool>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return ForgotPasswordFormDialog();
        });
  }

  @override
  @protected
  void onInitialise() {
    entity = const UserCredentialEntity();
    super.onInitialise();
  }

  @override
  void hydrateEntityFromForm() {
    entity = entity.copyWith(
        emailAddress:
            form.control(UserCredentialFieldNames.emailAddress).value as String,
        password:
            form.control(UserCredentialFieldNames.password).value as String);
  }

  @override
  @protected
  void hydrateFormFromEntity() {
    form.control(UserCredentialFieldNames.emailAddress).value =
        entity.emailAddress ?? '';

    form.control(UserCredentialFieldNames.password).value =
        entity.password ?? '';
  }

  @override
  @protected
  Future<UserCredential> submitMethod() {
    return entity.signIn();
  }

  @override
  @protected
  void onSubmitError(VpAppError<dynamic> error) {
    vpSnackBarError(
        title: 'Error Signing In', body: error.message ?? '', context: context);
  }

  /// Nothing required here as there is an authentication status riverpod
  /// listener which handles navigation when the authentication status changes
  @override
  void onSubmitSuccess(UserCredential result) {}
}
```

For some reason I get a compile time error:

```
lib/src/presentation/pages/unauthenticated/sign_in/sign_in_form_page/sign_in_form_view_model.dart:16:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'SignInFormViewModel' is missing implementations for these members:
     - AFormView.setupForm
    Try to either
     - provide an implementation,
     - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
     - mark the class as abstract, or
     - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
    class SignInFormViewModel
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    lib/src/presentation/common/forms/remote_form_view/a_remote_form_view.dart:20:8: Context: 'AFormView.setupForm' is defined here.
      void setupForm() {
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

Why am I seeing this error?

Comment: `ARemoteFormView` is not a mixin in your code, it is an abstract class. But you try to use it as mixin. Probably problem is here. Look - https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_mixin.html

Comment: @Mol0ko Thanks I think that is the right direction. I'm still unsure how to make a mixin inherit from a supertype though. Anyone know if this is possible?